# calculate the flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds

I am trying to solve the following

> For $q\in\Bbb R$, write $\ddot q = 1$ as a first-order system, find the flow $\Phi_t:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$, and verify that $\Phi_t\circ\Phi_s = \Phi_{t+s}$.

So far i have set 
$$ u = \frac{dq}{dt}
 \\u' = u\frac{du}{dt} = 1$$

I have tried to solve this for q and to then set the flow at $\Phi = q(t,q_0)$.

I am not sure if i am going about this correctly, would appreciate some advice on how to proceed.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it more readable.  In the future, try to write your questions using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so someone else doesn't have to.